# Angular 5 Authorization Header works in Safari but not in Chrome

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

I have an Angular 5 Application and a Spring Boot backend. The Angular app does a Google OAuth2 login and sends then the token through the Authorization header to the backend. The backend verifies the token.

If I do that in Chrome on localhost with ng serve, all works fine. I see the OAuth Token in the header like that:

```
Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlzNBbvSFMoQ429olweferferg8etr9g9rtg79t
```

...and the authorization works as expected (localhost in Chrome).

So If I deploy my angular app to my domain on the prod server, the authorization doesnt work. I dont see the Authorization header in Chromes Developer Tools, and also the backend doesn't authorize the client.

If I use the Safari Then it is working also on the prod Server.

So who has an idea where are the differents between localhost/prod server and Chrome/Safari regarding the Authorization Header.

Comment: Any error messages in console? This a cross-domain request by any chance? If so, maybe your server does not correctly indicate the allowed headers for CORS requests?

Comment: CORS is ok I managed that by the backend, and the response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to my client domain. The only error is an 404.

Comment: OK Sorry it works now, it seems there was an caching problem.